# Different area values in aggregate function

Tags: qgis, spherical-geometry, aggregate

In QGIS 3.22.8 the aggregate function used in text field shows planar area values instead of spherical. It happens in both the Print Layout and the Report.

How can I get the spherical values of the area? I used the following equation:

```
aggregate('polygon_layer','sum',$area)
```

Comment: Which extent of features/layer are we talking about, and how large is the difference?

Comment: I confirm the problem in QGIS 3.22.8, 3.26.0 and master. I recommend opening an issue here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues

Comment: Just draw a simple square 1000m x 1000m. In planar it gives 10e6 m2, as expected. Spherically, a bit more, but it depends on the location.
To reproduce the bug, open the Print composer or Report and create a Text Field with equation I wrote above. It will give the planimetric values, not the spherical.

Answer (score 2):

The expression works correctly if applied on the layer itself (e.g. Field calculator or labels) - but not if you use it in another context, where you don't work on a layer - like your use case, where you work in Print Layout. I'm not sure if it is a bug or a prinicipal limitation of the function `$area`, as it refers to the *current feature* - and outside of the layer, referring to the current feature seems to be different.

Workaround: use Field calculator to create an attribute `ellpsoidal_area` with `$area`, then aggregate/sum this field.

Comment: Isn't the aggregation function designed to overcome the _current feature_ limitation? 
I know the workaround but I'd like to avoid to clutter the data with unnecessary ballast.

Comment: This is a quite technical question that is maybe better asked at QGIS developer mailing list: https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/qgis-developer